# Google APIs in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, heroku

I consider myself a tinkerer and this is where my lack of fundamental knowledge really shows. I have a Facebook Bot up and running on a Heroku Node.js instance, and have successfully included several API libraries like Algorithmia for sentiment analysis. Now I want to use Google's NLP API, but I have no idea how to do go about doing that. I've found the following sample: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/language

But I can't seem to get it to work. What I did was download the repository and then put the "language" folder in my main folder. Then I tried to use require() in my main js file to include it as follows:

```
const analyze = require('./heroku/language');
```

However, this throws an error. My whole approach is probably fundamentally wrong, so I'd be really grateful if somebody could explain to me, how I can integrate a sample like this in my code!

EDIT: Here's the error that I get in the heroku logs:

```
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490340+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490337+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490340+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490341+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490339+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490336+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490337+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)
2016-07-25T08:32:36.490332+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
```

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your application and a sample of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted suggests that there is a missing dependency or an incorrectly required module.

You have to run `npm install` in the language folder for it to install all of it's dependencies.

Also make sure that the path you require on this line is correct `require('./heroku/language');`

Your approach should work, there are a number of [prerequisites](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/README.md#how-to-run-a-sample) listed in your module`s readme, make sure you've followed those.